# What Widget is Ubuntu's Settings Application Using for Lists?

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, gnome, glade

In Ubuntu, there are several places in the settings app that have a very nice list view, with add/remove buttons, including Appearance, Keyboard Layout, Privacy, Bluetooth, etc.  What widget(s) are they using?  I'm starting on my first Ubuntu app with Glade, and need that interface.

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of the interface you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code lives in [GNOME Control Centrer](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-control-center/) and it is not a widget.  There is a GtkTreeView for the list and below it, there is a GtkToolbar with two buttons (using the symbolic icons `list-add-symbolic` and `list-remove-symbolic`).  Instead of the GtkTreeView could be another widget, but the layout is the same.

You can see the glade files inside each `panel`.  For instance, [User Accounts](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-control-center/tree/panels/user-accounts/data/user-accounts-dialog.ui).

Comment: I was able to find the code in the source package on Launchpad and figure out how the interface was constructed, but I didn't realize the repository could be browsed online.  +1, thank you.

Comment: Just for anyone who wants to know in the future, you have to apply the `inline-toolbar` style class to the `GtkToolbar` widget for the attached-button look and the background gradient.